# Installing windows 2000 pro from hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows-installation, windows-2000

I'm wishing to install Windows 2000 Pro on my computer from a hard disk: Source of hard drive is from a discarded Dell computer, I have product code #.
  Computer to be installed on: I MAC, Snow Leopard, VM Ware install with Win 7 currently in portion. I have the adapter to access the hard drive and connect by USB.
  Is 2000 still a DOS based OS?

How do I go about install only the OS from the hard drive to a newly created portion in VM Ware? Will there be any issues with the OS be dedicated to from a Dell computer?

Please give a step by step instructions and active links for me to d this install, not really savvy as to how do this and please cover any over looked issues for the install.

Thanks

Comment: Windows 2000 is not DOS based (it's NT), a [bit of searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_2000) would reveal that to you.  Aside from that, you'll need to either get the Windows install media, or you can try to P2V it, or just use it as a HDD in the VM as-is and see if you can get it booting.  Anyhow, your question is too broad (IMO). Go try some stuff and come back and add the results, and explain where you're getting stuck exactly.

Comment: You need the `Windows 2000 Professional` installation disk in order to install `Windows 2000 Professional`.  It sounds like you don't have the required pieces to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A major problem with your plans, is that OEM windows installations search for a hardware ID on the motherboard at the start. Without a Dell motherboard ID, your IOS install is not going to get far.

There is also a licensing/ethical problem. Your Dell/Windows OS license was an agreement that that installation of windows could not be migrated to any other machine. The OEM COA sticker is not a useable windows license (ie - when prompted during a windows install for the license key, the valid looking text on the COA sticker will not work).